# Widget getTimeline method called multiple times for customized intents

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios14, widgetkit

In my iOS 14 widget with a single custom intent, when the user selects one intent, then changes to another, my `getTimeline` method is called multiple times for each intent on each refresh - including previously-selected ones.

I would expect `getTimeline` to only be called with the currently-selected intent. Is there a way to check whether the intent is the currently-selected intent? I make a network request in the `getTimeline` method and I do not want to make multiple requests when the widget only shows one intent.

As an example, I downloaded the [Emoji Ranger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/building_widgets_using_widgetkit_and_swiftui) sample code and added a print statement to the getTimeline method. I then:

1. Run the app and open it once.
2. Add a widget to the home screen.
3. Run the widget extension target on the simulator.
4. Select the character Egghead.
5. Select the character Cake.

This is what prints on the next widget refresh (usually ~15 mins):

```
- Timeline: nil
- Timeline: Optional("Egghead")
- Timeline: Optional("Cake")
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'll notify if I find something on the matter, hope you too

Comment: @MarckGorgon It seems as though this was fixed for iOS 14 release/Xcode 12. It doesn't call it multiple times for me, does it still happen for you? I'm not sure if I've tested it right...

Comment: I haven't checked on a physical device yet but I'm experiencing the same issue with Xcode 12.0.1

Comment: Still getting called multiple times with xcode 12.3 on a physical device.

Comment: This is still getting called twice every time for me, 12.5 on physical device.